# Alert called twice on Firebase response in ionic2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I used Firebase on ionic2 such like that:

```
firebase.database()
                    .ref("my_ref")
                    .orderByChild("my_field")
                    .equalTo(variable_field)
                    .on("value", (snapshot) => {
                        alert('Twice?');
                     });
```

Why does my `alert('Twice?')` shown two times? How to avoid these multiple times called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called twice because [`on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) invokes the callback with the current value of the requested data and invokes it again if the data changes.

If you only want the callback invoked once, use the [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method instead:

```js
firebase.database()
  .ref("my_ref")
  .orderByChild("my_field")
  .equalTo(variable_field)
  .once("value", (snapshot) => {
    alert('Once!');
  });
```